# CSS background-image does not display external / direct image url

Tags: html, css, reactjs, background-image

I'm trying to use the background-image CSS property to set the background of some nodes in a cytoscape-graph.

If I use:

```
'background-image': 'url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/computer-system-and-data/512/1-256.png)',
```

it works perfectly fine.

However, if I use this (the image I actually want to use):

```
'background-image': 'url(http://app.ardoq.com/api/attachment/workspace/5d6521661fa32c5a0ca7094b/Cop_Pink_Icon.png)'
```

the image does not load.

The difference between these two url's as far as I can see, is that the latter downloads the image instead of displaying it when I enter the image url in my browser.

Using the img-tag works with the latter URL when I'm in just plain HTML, so I'm not sure what's causing this URL not to be usable with the background-image CSS property:

```
<img src='http://app.ardoq.com/api/attachment/workspace/5d6521661fa32c5a0ca7094b/Cop_Pink_Icon.png'></img>
```

Comment: In image tag this link is getting me 404, probably thats the issue.

Comment: background-image don't need single quotation.

Comment: there is a redirection to httpS:// protocol, did you try to change it to 'https ://app.ardoq.com/api/attachment/workspace/5d6521661fa32c5a0ca7094b/Cop_Pink_Icon.png'

Comment: @Elen, thank you for the suggestion! I tried changing it to https as you suggested, but still no luck.

Comment: @IshitaRay, thank you for comment. This is styling done in javascript, hence the quotation marks. It works with the first image-url, so I don't believe that's the problem unfortunately.

Comment: might be an obvious one, but after changing to https - did you reload page with 'hard' refresh? i.e. for Chrome Cntrl + F5

Comment: @Elen, I did not, but I just tested it and it did not solve the problem :/

Comment: A way around would be to download the image and give `directory/Cop_Pink_Icon.png` in url

Comment: @PaulBaiju, good idea! Do you know if there's a way to do this during runtime? The image-url is part of the response of a API-request, so manually downloading each one would prove troublesome :/

Comment: UPDATE: Seems like the problem may lie with the image provider, as I got this message in the "network"-section in my browser:


"Access to image at 'https://app.ardoq.com/api/attachment/workspace/5d6521661fa32c5a0ca7094b/Cop_Pink_Icon.png' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"


Not sure why it worked using the img-tag though, hmm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this seemed to be a CORS-error, and I managed to fix it by adding a proxy to my image url. I used https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com as my proxy.

So instead of fetching the image from

```
https://app.ardoq.com/api/attachment/workspace/5d6521661fa32c5a0ca7094b/Cop_Pink_Icon.png
```

I fetch the image from this instead:

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://app.ardoq.com/api/attachment/workspace/5d6521661fa32c5a0ca7094b/Cop_Pink_Icon.png
```

Answer (score 0):

This image result is not found. I would recommend some icon hosting website like icons8.com if you would like to import custom icons in your project.

```html
<img src='https://app.ardoq.com/api/attachment/workspace/5d6521661fa32c5a0ca7094b/Cop_Pink_Icon.png'></img>
```